# C++ multiple for loop performance

Tags: c++

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
clock_t startTime, endTime;
double a = 1.2;
double b = 1.4;
double c = 1.0;
int iter = 1000000;

startTime = clock();
for (int i = 0; i < 4*iter; i++)
{
    a = b/c;
    a = b/c;
    a = b/c;
    a = b/c;
}
endTime = clock();

cout << "The run time is: " <<(double)(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "s" << endl;

startTime = clock();
for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
{
    a = b/c;
}
for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
{
    a = b/c;
}
for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
{
    a = b/c;
}
for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
{
    a = b/c;
}
endTime = clock();

cout << "The run time is: " <<(double)(endTime - startTime) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << "s" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
The run time is: 0.026394s                                                                                                                                                       
The run time is: 0.011601s
```

I do not understand. Actually I hope they have identical performance, but it is not. Any comments? Thanks.

Why it says "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.". I think I already add enough details...talk is cheap, show me the code..

Comment: How many times did you try? What was the optimization level?

Comment: Did you enable optimizations when you compiled?

Comment: Since the code does nothing but print out the clocks I'm surprised the compiler didn't optimize everything else out.

Comment: could you also add your compiler command? I think @user4581301 has a point. Maybe you have a different result when `iter` matters (maybe `a += b/c`) and you make use of the result (also print it?).

Comment: Did you try how the numbers change when you increase `iter` by a factors of 10, 100 or 1000?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the compiler was run without optimization, the loops do not perform the same count of operations.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4*iter; i++)
{
    a = b/c;
    a = b/c;
    a = b/c;
    a = b/c;
}
```

The first loop above performs **16 * iter** times the operation `a = b/c`.

Other four loops bellow perform in sum **4 * iter** times the operation `a = b/c`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < iter; i++)
{
    a = b/c;
}
```

Thus the second time period is shorter.

If you run the compiler with optimizations, you will get equal times (zeros). The compiler will get rid loops at all, since loop results are not used.